# Whether usdt or usdc freeze people accounts often?

Tags: usdt

Whether usdt or USDC will freeze the accounts often?
This happened a lot or?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the analytics...

There are [256 banned USDT addresses](https://explore.duneanalytics.com/public/dashboards/3zhIaRUCFgmZMKqHG0pguvSvw1aOGL8gxFtZ2ujf).

There is [1 banned USDC address](https://explore.duneanalytics.com/public/dashboards/QMiStmCNNcVmzf2BbW12njfGRTUPz373hkgcH7JB). (Which is probably why USDC hasn't been in the news as much.)

Regardless of how often this happens, the fact that it can happen at all should be the main concern* when using centralised stablecoins.

**Edit:**

*One of the main concerns. Lack of audits, and questions about how collateralised the reserves are would be others :-)

Comment: In case someone knows, calling `confirmTransaction` bans a USDT address? How?

Comment: Looks like in advance they've set up a reference to `addBlackList()` with the relevant arguments in their `transactions[]` array (using `submitTransaction()`), then `confirmTransaction()` confirms that they want to run said transaction, which then makes an internal transaction to the Tether BlackList contract. I think. Not sure why they've used that architecture :-)

Answer (score 1):

Althought USDT is deployed on the mainnet and transactions are executed in a decentralized way, the administration of the Tether smart contract is entirely centralized (as it is the case for a large amount of projects) and users have to trust the private company behind the stablecoin. Indeed, as you mention, the contract owner has the possibility to freeze the transfer of a specific account using this function :

```
    function addBlackList (address _evilUser) public onlyOwner {
    isBlackListed[_evilUser] = true;
    AddedBlackList(_evilUser);
}
```

Owner can also burn a user's funds with :

```
    function destroyBlackFunds (address _blackListedUser) public onlyOwner {
    require(isBlackListed[_blackListedUser]);
    uint dirtyFunds = balanceOf(_blackListedUser);
    balances[_blackListedUser] = 0;
    _totalSupply -= dirtyFunds;
    DestroyedBlackFunds(_blackListedUser, dirtyFunds);
}
```

Does this happen often?

The answer is no, as the company would take a huge reputational risk acting like this. According to this [article](https://news.bitcoin.com/tether-freezes-millions-of-dollars-usdt-40-addresses/), Tether freezed 40 accounts between 2017 and 2020 to respect law enforcement. This happened recently with the freeze of the Kucoin hacker account on September 2020.

For USDC I believe the answer is the same.

Comment: Thanks since usdt banned 256 addresses and USDC banned 1 address, does this mean USDC is more reliable than usdt? So I keep my assets in USDC better than in usdt?

Comment: No because USDC is much less used than USDT, so we cannot really compare them on this point.